# List all the files ending with 10 or 11 or 12

Tags: wildcards

To list all the files ending with 10 or 11 or 12 I have tried `ls *[10-12]` and `ls *[10,11,12]` but these are not working. I don't know why. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `ls *[10,11,12]` works well for me

Comment: @UVV If you have a file ending on 20, 21 or 22 it will be listed.

Comment: @UVV That would apply `ls` to all names ending in `0`, `1`, `2` or `,`.  If that is what you want, then it "works", but it would be better written as `ls *[0-2,]` or `ls *[012,]`.

Answer (score 17):

`[...]` matches *one* character (*collating element* in some shells) if it's in the specified set.

`[10-12]` means either character `1` or characters from `0` to `1` or character `2` so the same as `[102]` or `[0-2]`¹.

`[10,11,12]` means either `1`, `0`, `,`, `1`... So the same as `[,0-2]`.

Here you want:

```
ls -d -- *1[0-2]
```

That is, (non-hidden) filenames that end in 1 followed by any of the `0`, `1` or `2` characters.

Now beware that it also matches `foo110` or `foo112345612`.

If you don't want that, then you'd need something like:

```
ls -d -- *[!0-9]1[0-2] 1[0-2]
```

That would however not match `foo010`

If out of `foo10`, `foo00010`, `foo110` you want `foo10` and `foo00010` to match, then with `ksh` or `bash -O extglob` or `zsh -o kshglob`:

```
ls -d -- !(*[0-9])*(0)1[0-2]
```

Note that except with `zsh`, if any of those pattern's don't match, the patterns will be passed as-is to `ls`, so you may end up listing unwanted files if there are files named like that. With `bash`, you can set the `failglob` option to work around that.

`zsh` is the only shell that has a glob operator to match ranges of numbers.

```
ls -d -- *<10-12>
```

would match files ending in a number from 10 to 12. It would also match `foo110` since that's `foo1` followed by `10`. You could do (with `extendedglob`):

```
ls -d -- (^*[0-9])<10-12>
```

though.

`zsh` is also the shell that introduced the `{10..12}` type of brace expansion (copied by ksh93 and bash a few years later).

However, like the `{10,11,12}` equivalent, that is *not* globbing. That's a form of expansion that is done before globbing.

```
ls -d -- *{10..12}
```

is first expanded to:

```
ls -d -- *10 *11 *12
```

If any of those 3 globs fails, then the command is aborted in `zsh` (and `bash -O failglob`).

---

<sup>¹ though note that in several shells and locales, including `bash` on a GNU system in a typical UTF-8 locale such as `en_US.UTF-8`, `[0-1]` may match on a lot more characters than just 0 and 1 including things like ٠۰߀०০੦૦୦௦౦౸೦൦෦๐໐༠༳၀႐០៰᠐᥆᧐᪀᪐᭐᮰᱀᱐⁰₀↉⓪⓿〇㍘꘠꣐꤀꧐꧰꩐꯰０</sup>

Answer (score 8):

Try this :

```
ls *{10,11,12}
```

or

```
ls -l *{10,11,12}
```

(cannot show hidden files)

Comment: You can use `shopt -s dotglob` (in bash) if you want to see dotfiles as well.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
ls -d -- *1[0-2]
```

Remember that `[]` represents a set of characters and in case of numbers it can go from [0-9]

Comment: `[]` doesn't represent a range by itself, just a pattern to match upon. the `-` makes it a range inside that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`ls *@(10|11|12)` is what you're looking for.

This requires `extglob` to be enabled using [shopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html), i.e., `shopt -s extglob`. In addition, you can append that line to `~/.bashrc` to permanently enable it.

For more information on why this works, see [the official Bash manual page on pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html).